# Use of R lag function in amortization calculations

Tags: r

I'm trying to build a view of amortized loan repayment in R.
I have all of the component variables and inputs, yet I haven't been able to successfully use the equivalent of SQL's LAG() function to reduce the outstanding value when the previous instalment value is subtracted from it.

```
amount_borrowed <- 900
term <- 9
instalments <- 100 
start_date <- as.Date('2019-03-01') 
end_date <- (start_date + months(term))
date <- data.frame(seq(start_date, end_date, by="months"))
```

Desired output:

```
|--------|------------|---------|
| date   | instalment | balance |                                               
|--------|------------|---------|
| Mar-19 |     100    |   900   |                                     
| Apr-19 |     100    |   800   | 
| May-19 |     100    |   700   | 
| Jun-19 |     100    |   600   |
```

etc etc

I have tried various ways of achieving the above including creating a UDF and using SQLDF (as shown below) on which I would then use iterative subtractions, but it's really inelegant and I'd quite like to not have to resort to SQLDF as I so often do.

```
SELECT 
 date,
 instament,
 balance,
 LAG(balance,1) OVER (
 PARTITION BY date
 ORDER BY date 
 ) next_balance 
FROM 
mydataframe
```

Any help greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

Thanks all for the help and guidance thus far.
I have added new complexity which has slightly changed the approach and therefore requirement. I will show my methodology below.

Essentially I need to incorporate interest and capital payments to the calculations.
Let's call interest 2.2% of the *outstanding* balance and say that capital is calculated as being interest - instalment.

Here are the inputs:

```
# inputs
start_date <- as.Date("2019-03-01")
amount <- 250000
instalment <- 750 
interest_rate1 <- 0.0220  
term <- 35
end_date <- (start_date + years(term))
```

At the start of the loan things are thus:

```
df_one <- data.frame(start_date, instalment = NA , balance = amount, interest = NA, capital = NA)
```

[image]

I have then derived dates for the full term of the loan as follows;

```
all_term_dates <- data.frame(seq(start_date, end_date, by="months"))
    colnames(all_term_dates)[1] <- "start_date"
```

I then remove the first row because I already have this in the format I want and now just need the point at which the repyaments begin.

```
all_dates_start <- data.frame(all_term_dates$start_date[-1])
colnames(all_dates_start)[1] <- "start_date"
```

I then put placeholder variables in the dataframe to populate later

```
all_dates_start$instalment <- NA
all_dates_start$balance <- NA 
all_dates_start$interest <- NA
all_dates_start$capital <- NA
```

I then union the first dataframe with the dates and placeholders

```
df_two <- rbind(df_one, all_dates_start)
```

..before adding the following calculations

```
df_two[["interest"]] <-interest_rate1 * lag(df_two$balance)/12
df_two[["capital"]] <- instalment - df_two$interest
df_two[["balance"]] <- lag(df_two$balance) - df_two$capital
df_two[["instalment"]] <- instalment
```

My questions are as follows;

1) How can I do this elegantly and recursively such that interest continues to be a function of the interest rate and the previous balance value?

Once more, help is appreciated. Still fairly inexperienced with R and wish to develop. Not afraid of trying hard and failing.

Comment: I think one way of conceptualising this is that you're subtracting `cumsum(data$instalment)` from the original `data$balance` value. I don't think you need to use lag logic necessarily.

Comment: @thelatemail If I read correctly, the OP already has the rolling sum handled, and just wants to compute the lag.

Comment: Based on the discussion here it is not really clear what the question is. Is it to generate the table listed as *Desired output* or is it to simply lag some variable and the whole discussion of amortization is irrelevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can try

```
data.frame(date, instalments,balance = amount_borrowed - instalments * seq(0, term))

#         date instalments balance
#1  2019-03-01         100     900
#2  2019-04-01         100     800
#3  2019-05-01         100     700
#4  2019-06-01         100     600
#5  2019-07-01         100     500
#6  2019-08-01         100     400
#7  2019-09-01         100     300
#8  2019-10-01         100     200
#9  2019-11-01         100     100
#10 2019-12-01         100       0
```

**data**

```
amount_borrowed <- 900
term <- 9
instalments <- 100 
start_date <- as.Date('2019-03-01') 
end_date <- (start_date + months(term))
date <- seq(start_date, end_date, by="months")
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr` package actually has a `lag()` function:

```
df$next_balance <- lag(df$balance)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want last month's balance to match your SQL solution. I've also included last month's installment if you need that for any calculation.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  date = c("2019-03-01", "2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01"),
  installment = c(100, 100, 100, 100),
  balance = c(900, 800, 700, 600)
)

df <- df %>%
  arrange(date) %>% # in case the months were already not ordered
  mutate(
    date = format(as.Date(date), "%b-%y"), # change format of date
    previous_month_installment = lag(installment),
    previous_month_balance = lag(balance)
  )
head(df)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   date   installment balance previous_month_installme… previous_month_bala…
#>   <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>                     <dbl>                <dbl>
#> 1 Mar-19         100     900                        NA                   NA
#> 2 Apr-19         100     800                       100                  900
#> 3 May-19         100     700                       100                  800
#> 4 Jun-19         100     600                       100                  700
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

### lag a variable

There seems to be a question regarding what is being asked but if the question is how to lag a variable then an easy way is to use `lag` on a `ts` class variable where the -1 means lag forward (or omit the -1 if you want to lag backward).  No packages are used.

```
balance <- ts(seq(900, 0, -100), start = c(2019, 3), freq = 12)
lag(balance, -1)
```

*Note* One gotcha if you are using packages is that some packages (xts, dplyr) define a `lag` function that is backwards relative to the standard set by R.  At least with xts it only applies to xts objects so it does no harm if you are not using `lag` on xts objects but dplyr not only defines it in a reverse sense but can overwrite the `lag` generic so that it can't be used in other packages.  As a result be sure that dplyr is *not* loaded if you are using `lag` from base R or from another package.

### Generated table listed as Desired Output

If the question is how to generate the table listed as *Desired output* then you don't need `lag`.  With judicious use of `seq`, `diff` and `cumsum` we can avoid the use of `lag` entirely here.  We discuss two sets of alternate assumptions.

**1)** With a constant installment (as in the question), if we calculate `balance` first then we don't need `lag` and we don't need the date pre-calculation shown in the question since we can derive the length.  No packages are used.

```
# inputs
start_date <- as.Date("2019-03-01")
amount <- 900
installment <- 100

balance = seq(amount, 0, -installment)
data.frame(date = seq(start_date, by = "month", length = length(balance)),
           installment = c(-diff(balance), 0), 
           balance)
```

**2)** If the installments were in a vector and sum to the initial balance then:

```
# inputs
start_date <- as.Date("2019-03-01")
installments <- rep(100, 9)

data.frame(date = seq(start_date, by = "month", length = length(installments) + 1),
           installment = c(installments, 0),
           balance = sum(installments) - cumsum(c(0, installments)))
```

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck, this helped greatly however I have now expanded upon the requirements somehwhat. Please see edit.